# Accessing an attribute from a nested tag XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to access the attribute of a tag that exists several layers beneath the current tag.

For example: 
A snippet of the XML looks like this

```
<Content version="Title" action="add">
  <ProgramContent>
    <ContentMetaData>
      <ContentId>
        <HouseNumber>558960</HouseNumber>
        <AlternateId idType="SeriesId" authoritativeSource="BCM">19714</AlternateId>
        <AlternateId idType="EntityId" authoritativeSource="BCM">550133</AlternateId>
      </ContentId>
     </ContentMetaData>
   </ProgramContent>
</Content>
```

and my code currently looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content">
   <xsl:if test="string(@version)= 'Title'">
     <xsl:if test="string(//AlternateId[@idType ='SeriesId'])">
       <test>hey</test>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I need to do a for-each loop on the content tag to check through all of them but then within that for-each loop I only want to continue operations if the attribute of the AlternateID tags doesn't contain seriesId. So if either of them are seriesId I want to end the if statement. How do I do this? As you can see I've tried an if statement that should check if the attribute idType is equal to SeriesId but it fails and doesn't return anything, am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `string()` returns a string, but what you want is a Boolean. Something like `test=//AlternateId[contains(@idType, 'SeriesId')]` should work better.

Comment: Yes, though it should be ".//" rather than "//" because you want descendants of the context node, not nodes anywhere in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to loop over all `<Content>` elements that don't have a `<AlternateID>` element with the `idType="SeriesId"`.

You can do that directly into the `xsl:for-each` like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content[descendant::ns0:AlternateID/@idType != 'SeriesId']">
```

Comment: the content elements also have to have a version of Title too, is it possible to write two arguments directly into the for each loop?

Comment: Yes, just add another predicate.

Comment: Cheers, you've been incredibly useful!